# Calling a function twice and passing different arguments - first call works but second returns null

Tags: python

I am creating a function to query through a CSV and the function works, the issue that I am running into is that when I call the function more than once it runs the first time, but doesn't run the second time.

```
def item_Cost(personName):
    Total = 0;
    Items = '';
    queryName = '';
    for line in csv_reader:
      if(line[0] == personName):
        queryName = line[0];
        # **** QUERY AND CONCAT ITEMS ****
        Items += line[2] + ',';
        # **** ADDING COST ****
        if(line[3] == ''):
          line[3] = 0;
        Total += float(line[3]);
    print(f'NAME: {queryName} ITEMS: {Items} TOTAL COST: {Total}');
```

When I make these calls individually the function executes perfectly, when I try to run them at the same time I get the following output.

```
item_Cost('Candice');
item_Cost('Alycia');
```

Output:

```
NAME: Candice ITEMS: Salad 3,Snack 3,Snack 2,Bowl 3, TOTAL COST: 23.5
NAME:  ITEMS:  TOTAL COST: 0
```

Comment: Both should actually fail, due to ```csv_reader``` being undefined. Could you clarify how do you get this variable anyway?

Comment: Also - your question is badly missing context - please provide sample data (which I suppose is under this ```csv_reader```) - preferably in string format

Comment: And please remove the semicolons from your code!

Comment: Is `csv_reader` a single global csv reader on a file opened once?

Comment: This code has many issues. Variable and function_names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `csv_reader` object seems to live outside of the function. The second time you call the function, it still refers to the same `csv_reader` as before - and that reader has already read to the end of the file.

Move the initialization of `csv_reader` inside your function instead if you want to read through the file twice and decouple it from outside logic.

Comment: Since it lives outside the function- first run would also fail. Cause no ```csv_reader``` was defined.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski No, functions have access to the variables defined outside of them - they can't however re-assign them (i.e. assign a a new value).